# Elasticsearch saves document as string of array, not array of strings

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5, elasticsearch-ruby

I am trying to contain [array](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/array.html) as a document value.
I succeed it in "tags" field as below;

This document contains array of strings.

```
curl -XGET localhost:9200/MY_INDEX/_doc/132328908

#=> {
  "_index":"MY_INDEX",
  "_type":"_doc",
  "_id":"132328908",
  "found":true,
  "_source": {
    "tags": ["food"]
  }
}
```

However, when I am putting items in the same way as above,
the document is SOMETIMES like that;

```
curl -XGET localhost:9200/MY_INDEX/_doc/328098989

#=> {
  "_index":"MY_INDEX",
  "_type":"_doc",
  "_id":"328098989",
  "found":true,
  "_source": {
    "tags": "[\"food\"]"
  }
}
```

This is string of array, not array of strings, which I expected.

```
"tags": "[\"food\"]"
```

It seems that this situation happens randomly and I could not predict it.
How could it happen?

Note:
・I use elasticsearch-ruby client to index a document.
This is my actual code;

```
es_client = Elasticsearch::Client.new url: MY_ENDPOINT

es_client.index(
   index: MY_INDEX,
   id: random_id, # defined elsewhere
   body: {
      doc:  {
         "tags": ["food"]
      },
   }
)
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you share an example of how you put the doc into Elastic? all the insert command include the doc

Comment: Hi, Thanks. `curl -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H 'Accept: application/json'  -X PUT -d '{ "tags": ["food", "trip" ] localhost:9200/MY_INDEX/_doc/239879`

Comment: This is my PUT command and the response is like that:

Comment: `{"_index":"MY_INDEX","_type":"_doc","_id":"239879","_version":4,"result":"updated","_shards":{"total":2,"successful":1,"failed":0},"_seq_no":25,"_primary_term":1}`

Comment: `curl -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H 'Accept: application/json'  -X POST -d '{ "tags": ["food", "trip" ]}' "localhost:9200/test/_doc` always works fine for me. Are you really inserting all your records using `curl`?

Comment: oh... I am so sorry for my oversimplification. Actually, I use elasticsearch-ruby client to index a document(https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-ruby). I add a note for that in my question. Thank you so much.